# Removing special characters from gridview data

Tags: c#, gridview, alphanumeric

I have a `gridview` `object` that I am using to bind to a `datasource`. Upon the `selectedIndexChanging` event of the `gridview`, I would like to bring the data shown in the `gridview` into the `textboxes` on the form. However, when the data contains alphanumeric characters such as &'"", the data from the grid is showing ;amp, #S etc. and all other weird characters whenever I enter an alphanumeric character. Is there a way to prevent these characters from popping up in the `textboxes` when taking data from the grid?
The code that I have so far:

protected void grdActions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
            int selectedRow1 = grdActions.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
            hdnIndexNo.Value = grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[1].Text;
            ddlActionType.SelectedValue = grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[3].Text;


            if (grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[4].Text == null || grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[4].Text == string.Empty || grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[4].Text == "&nbsp;")
            {
                txtDetails.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                txtDetails.Text = grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[4].Text;
            }

            if (grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[5].Text == null || grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[5].Text == string.Empty || grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[5].Text == "&nbsp;")
            {
                txtCompletedDate.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                txtCompletedDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[5].Text).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            }

            ddlActionOwner.SelectedValue = grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[7].Text;

            if (grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[8].Text == null || grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[8].Text == string.Empty || grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[8].Text == "&nbsp;")
            {
                txtAssignedTo.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                txtAssignedTo.Text = grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[8].Text;
            }


            if (grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[9].Text == null || grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[9].Text == string.Empty || grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[9].Text == "&nbsp;")
            {
                lblComments.Visible = false;
                txtComments.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblComments.Visible = true;
                txtComments.Visible = true;
                txtComments.Text = grdActions.Rows[selectedRow1].Cells[9].Text;
            }
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried thus far... And I mean the code.

Comment: Do not reject special characters.  Instead, you need to fix your code so that they are displayed correctly.  Please show us your code.

Comment: Alphanumeric characters are actually characters, that either represent a letter, such as a or b, or a number. Your special characters &'"" are not alphanumeric.

Comment: I added the code that I have for the selectedindexchanged event of the gridview. I had tried using server.htmlencode for assigning values to txtComments and txtDetails. However, it gave me the same results for the alphanumeric characters. I was thinking of using a Regex function to find the alphanumeric characters and replacing them...

Comment: I used the server.htmldecode() when converting the text from the gridview to the textboxes and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Server.HTMLDecode() when transferring the data fromthe gridview to the textboxes. This ensured that all special characters were removed before it was sent back to the textboxes on the form